# Flutter IOS: Problem with AutoFill of login form

Tags: ios, flutter, authentication, autofill

I have a two TextFields (email and password) wrapped in an AutoFillGroup.
The fields are filled correctly when I am focusing the email text field, but not when I am focusing the password input. Instead of filling the password, it focuses the email field.

I only have the issue on iOS.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: AutofillGroup(
      child: Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(
          16.00,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                alignLabelWithHint: true,
                label: Text('Email'),
              ),
              autofillHints: [
                AutofillHints.email,
              ],
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                alignLabelWithHint: true,
                label: Text('Password'),
              ),
              obscureText: true,
              autofillHints: [
                AutofillHints.password,
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Have you resolved the issue?

Comment: Nope. This is a well known issue. But I didn't try to look further yet